# Vertical spacing without new line

Tags: spacing

I am new to LaTeX and have a weird task. I need to write a line between two others. Think of like that:

```
foo boo doo(1)

              you soup pope(3)

doo boo foo(2)
```

But the thing is I am not allowed to add a new line between (1) and (2). In other words, (3) must be in between. How do I do such a thing?

Comment: Why are you not allowed to add a new line? Is this some kind of homework assignment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917694/spacing-in-latex?noredirect=1). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: In its current form, your question might not get many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what I mean, please ask for clarification using the Comment function. Specifically, elaborate on your interpretation of "new line" and show what you've attempted thus far to achieve such output.

Comment: @Darhuuk yeap, that is a meaningless homework

Comment: @Cagatay: It is not encouraged

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, then here is your answer: use a `raisebox` in an `llap`. Working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
\noindent foo boo doo(1)\llap{\raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{doo boo foo(2)}}

\noindent you soup pope(3)

\noindent\phantom{doo boo foo(2)}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, invitamus me missam ne velocitate renovasti dolorum.

\end{document}
```

[image: Minimal Working Example]

Comment: An even more sophisticated solution is to use `\baselineskip`:

`\noindent foo boo doo(1)\llap{\raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{doo boo foo(2)}}`

Comment: You could even use a phantom copy of the second line after writing the third, see my updated answer. Sorry for the `\noindent`s.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple `minibox` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
foo boo doo(1)\\%[0.5cm]
doo boo foo(2)
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    you soup pope(3)
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

if you remove the `%` comment character in the `%[0.5cm]` you get:

[image]

---

If the content happens to be in a table, you could adapt the solution from [Table: Can I shift a column by half the height of a row?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29537/table-can-i-shift-a-column-by-half-the-height-of-a-row) to yield similar results:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand*{\movedown}[1]{\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{#1}}}%
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\movedown}r<{\endcollectcell}}% (M for Middle)

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lM}
foo boo doo(1) & you soup pope(3)\\
doo boo foo(2)\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The `@{}` is simply used to eliminate the column spacing on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
\noindent
foo boo doo\\
doo boo foo\\
\raisebox{1.7\baselineskip}[0pt]{\hspace{8em}you soup pope}
```

[image]