# How can I shift a column in a table by half the row height?

Tags: tables

I need to shift the rightmost column of a table by half the height of a row.  This [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29537) was asked on Stack Exchange on September 26, 2011 by *fuenfundachtzig* with two excellent answers.  The title of the question was "Can I shift a column by half the height of a row?"

I tried to implement the solutions from both answers exactly as they were presented.  I typed in both solutions as a sample, but MiKTeX failed to compile either of them.  All I got was the error message

```
Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \cc@@case.
```

The non-working example I am focussed on right now is the solution given by *egreg* on September 26, 2011 in [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29537).  I typed it in exactly as shown in [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29537), including the use of A4 paper, which we do not use in the U.S.  I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) running under Windows XP.  The error message is as shown above.

In response to Zarko's request for my non-working example, I began to type it in and--to my surprise--I found that I had omitted a \ from \endcollectcell.  I am commenting here, rather than in in the comments section, because the question is closed and comments are not allowed.

I feel foolish for making such a simple mistake.  Many thanks to Rmano and Zarko, and any others who wasted any time reading my question.  I am deeply grateful for your help, which solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We need more information about your problem. Please at least provide link to mentioned question and also show what you tray so far.

Comment: The original question is at tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29537  and it gives a very clear example of what I need to do.   So far I tried both answers to that question, but neither one will compile under MikTeX.

Comment: I took liberty and wrote your link into question that is better visible for all. I also tested both answer with recent version ( 21.6.289) `MiKTeX` and they work fine (no warnings, no errors). Since you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem, we cant help you.

Comment: The OP is probably using some fragile command in the argument of the table, but as @Zarko says, without an [minimal working or non-working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) it's impossible to help.

Comment: Please, show code of your document by which you test @greg answer. My test of this answer gives expected result, without any warnings and errors. This means, that this answer is not cause of your problem. So we cannot confirm your claims because we don't know, what you really doing.